# C# Joining two tables on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not getting any output on gridview after using below code, am I not joining tables properly

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(this.Request.QueryString["outageID"]);
int y = Convert.ToInt32(this.Request.QueryString["toolid"]);
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("xyz");//connection name
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblOutageTransactionDetails,tbltools where  ToolsOutageID = " + x + "and toolid = " + y, con);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables;
GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message in your code? Did you try your query in your management studio first? It works? If it doesn't what error message you got? What are the types of these columns? Be more specific when you ask.

Comment: The `GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables;` looks suspicious... Try `GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` instead.

Comment: there is no error ,it is providing me some garbage output in gridview" casesensitive isinitialize table name....."

Comment: Please don't do select * from 2 tables, especially if you're doing a cartesian join. Only select the rows you absolutely need so you limit the traffic between database and client.

Comment: Also along with above comment there must be one space before and in your query `" + x + "and `

Comment: Please give the full error in an edit of your post.

Answer (score 0):

As Soner correctly says your info is limited, however if you get an exception on your query try to leave a space before `and` and make select only from 1 table at a time:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblOutageTransactionDetails where  ToolsOutageID = " + x + " and toolid = " + y, con);
```